# Цигикач - хто це? Цигикач - нормативне слово?

Tags: значення-слів

Із сайту [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87/)

> Замініть невластиву українській мові конструкцію з горе- (горе-вчений,
>   горе-досягнення) на: біда, а не (вчений), лихо, а не (досягнення),
>   попсуй-майстер, **цигикач**.

Цікавить слово ***"цигикач"***, в словниках його не знайшла.

Хто такий цигикач? Як його правильно вживати?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OnlineCorrector переказує пораду Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича з «Як ми говоримо»:

> #### [Горе-вчений, горе-майстер, біда, а не вчений, попсуй-майстер, цигикач, цигикало, ґанджа-андибер](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/hore-vchenyj-hore-majster-bida-a-ne-vchenyj)
>
> «Цей горе-вчений мав зухвалість заперечувати досягнення справжніх учених і вихваляв свої горе-досягнення», — читаємо в репортерській замітці. Нас дивує, що автор двічі вдається до однакової частини складених слів: «горе-вчений» і «горе-досягнення». Невже в українській мові нема інших слів, щоб уникнути цього повторення? Ні, вони є, але, мабуть, автор не знає їх. Замість «горе-вчений» можна сказати: біда, а не вчений, замість «горе-досягнення» — лихо, а не досягнення. У народній мові є дуже поширений вислів попсуй-майстер: «Цього попсуй-майстра тільки гукни — відразу переведе леміш на швайку, а з швайки зробить пшик» (із живих уст). Замість вислову «горе-музикант» у народі воліють казати цигикач («Хіба Войтенко вміє на скрипці грати? Тільки цигикає. То цигикач, а не музика». — З живих уст), цигикало.
>
> Замість «горе-богатир» Російсько-український словник за редакцією А. Кримського пропонував іронічний вислів ґанджа-андибер від імені героя історичної думи Хвеська Ґанджі-Андибера. Що ж — і такий вислів може знадобитися в творі відповідного жанру.
>
> А взагалі не слід користуватись одним висловом, коли є їх кілька, та ще, до того, таких соковитих, як ті, що наведено вище. Учімося в народу образності вислову! Це в народній пісні чуємо: «Ой лихо не Петрусь — лице біле, чорний вус».

Слово *цигикач* зустрічається [в таких словниках](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

- Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.):

  > Го́ре = <…>. — Го́ре-музыка́нтъ = циги́кач. <…>
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Гуди́ла, гуди́льщикъ = гудїй, гуду́н (С. Аф.), циги́кач.
- Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська):

  > Горе
  >   • <…>
  >   • Горе-музыкант – горе-музика; (розм.) цигикач (зниж. цигикало).
  >   • <…>
- Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов):

  > Го́ре –
  >   1) <…>
  >   • <…>
  >   • Го́ре-музыкант – циги́кач.
  >   • <…>
  >   2) <…>

Але в літературі ([Google Книги](//books.google.com/books?q=%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87) і [корпус GRAC-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[word=%22%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87.*%22])) я майже не бачу траплянь цього слова. Єдині два трапляння — це [журнал «Березіль» за 1996](//books.google.com/books?id=oBIyAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87) і [«У царстві сваволі (стежка додому)» Івана Губки](//books.google.com/books?id=TZcjAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87), все інше — це посилання на «Як ми говоримо» і вищенаведені словники.

А сучасні словники й зовсім не наводять цього слова. Та й частина старих словників відмічали його як розмовне. Ймовірно, колись це було справді вживане розмовне слово (недарма ж Уманець і Кримський його пропонували в словниках), але письменники його не підхопили, й слово почало забуватися.